# Possible to set up rails-like associations in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, orm, sqlalchemy, associations

In Rails, you can set up associations so that if you had an Article and Category model and 'category' was an column of 'Article' you could do:

```
article.category --> returns the category Object
```

but in SQLAlchemy, I can only do:

```
article.category --> only returns the category's id
```

Is there a way to get the Category object using SQLAlchemy? I am currently using the Declarative style of defining models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you haven't read the documentation on setting up ORM relationships.

http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/relationships.html

Answer (score 6):

You can create relationship like

```
category_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('category.id'))
category = relationship('Category')
```

This way you will get the object when you are accessing category.

Comment: Thanks I ended up doing this!

Comment: I appreciate you posting an answer instead of just chastising the asker with documentation.